# Why was this answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers, moderation

I'm talking about this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/46198/4732

As one can see, one moderator has deleted the answer. He doesn't mention anything under the answer (in comments) as to why the answer was being deleted.

The answer is answering the question. So it's not "not an answer". Only shortcoming that the answer has is that it does not cite sources. But for that one can add the citation needed banner and request the author to add the needed sources.

I'm curious to know why was it deleted in such a blunt manner given that it's not spam or abusive and is answering the question too?

Comment: Do you know any reason behind the two down-votes to that answer?

Comment: No I don't know ... may be because there were no sources? @hanugm

Comment: What is your guess? @hanugm

Comment: I m confused. I have a doubt that it is due to the sect war or initial version of answer might be an issue.

Comment: The original answer was quite short but it was answering the question. Only thing it didn't have is the proper source. That it was very short might be one reason and that it didn't have sources might be the other reason. @hanugm

Comment: Yeah true. Lacking reference is the key one.

Comment: @Rickross I have edited the answer.  The answer was also edited by another user. See whether the answer is okay now.

Comment: Yes the answer is perfectly okay. You two have done a good job in providing the sources.@GIRIBLR

Comment: @Rickross Thank you very much, sir. However, the downvote has not been removed yet.

Comment: Yes noticed that one downvote is still there. @GIRIBLR. It is very rare that downvoters will visit the post and undo downvotes (if needed).

Comment: @Rickross There were two downvotes, now there is only one. so we should be happy !

Comment: Yes, one downvote was probably from the author of the question himself who upon seeing the updated answer removed it. But the other user might not be even aware that the answer was improved. Or if aware doesn't want to remove it still. @GIRIBLR

Comment: @Rickross Indeed. I had sent a comment to the author of the question to accept the answer after the answer was edited. I guess he removed the downvote and accepted the answer.

Comment: That's great help from your side. If other users are also concerned like you it would have been better :) @GIRIBLR